# Check if user position is withing the area of 2 geopoints in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, geolocation, geometry

How do I check if the user geolocation is in the square area defined by 2 geopoints that define the square diagonal? 
Like in the next photo.[image]

How do I make a function that returns true if the user geolocation is in the white square defined by those 2 points?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bool overlaps(Rect other)` method..

1. Create a Rect from user location with 1 radius

   `Rect userRect = Rect.fromCircle(center:Offset(UserPositionDx,UserPositionDy),radius:1);`
2. Create a Rect from PointA and PointB ( Please check whether these points are defined as Offset(double dx,double dy) if not convert it to Offset )

   `Rect areaSquare = Rect.fromPoints(PointA,PointB);`
3. Create a bool variable and set it
   false at the begining
   `bool isUserInArea=false;`
4. Check if user position (as Rect with 1 radius) is overlaped by area

   `isUserInArea=areaSquare.overlaps(userRect);`